# PHP Form data not being passed

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a rather basic question but I just cant get my head around it.

I have a PHP form that has been working well for ages, all of a sudden, the php form values are not being passed with the post data. to trouble shoot I started removing some lines from my form, I got to a certain point where the for started working again. So I added a line back and it just stopped? I cant explain this at all. I checked the post_max_size setting and its 120m so cant be the problem. even the POST value of the submit button is not being passed. print_r() shows no data.

My full form (which used to work) is:

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="bsassigncosts.php" method="post">
<table id="hor-minimalist-a">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Date & Time</th>
        <th>Parked</th>
        <th><font color=red>Load Number</font></th>
        <th><font color=red>Trailer</font></th>
        <th><font color=red>Weight</font> kg's</th>
        <th><font color=red>Source</font></th>
        <th><font color=red>Destination</font></th>
        <th><font color=red>Cycle Type</font></th>
        <th><font color=red>Rate to be applied</font></th>
        <th>LOC Status / Comments</th>
    </tr>

<? while($row = $loads->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>"></td>
        <td><? echo $row['sarrive']; ?></td>
        <td><input type="radio"  <? if($row['parkinglot']==="yes"){echo "checked='checked'";} ?> disabled >&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="correctedloadnumber<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>" id="correctedloadnumber<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>" value="<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>" class="inputsmall"></td>
        <td>
            <SELECT name="correctedtrailer<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>" id="correctedtrailer<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>"  class="selectnarrow"> 
            <OPTION value="<? echo $row['trailer']; ?>" selected ><? echo $row['trailer']; ?></option>
            <option>
            <?=$optionstrailer?> 
            </option>
            </SELECT> 
        </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="correctedweight<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>" id="correctedweight<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>" value="<? echo $row['weight']; ?>" class="inputsmall"></td>
        <td>
            <SELECT name="correctedsource<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>" id="correctedsource<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>"  class="selectnarrow"> 
            <OPTION value="<? echo $row['source']; ?>" selected ><? echo $row['source']; ?></option>
            <option>
            <?=$optionssource?> 
            </option>
            </SELECT> 
        </td>
        <td>
            <SELECT name="correcteddestination<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>" id="correcteddestination<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>"  class="selectnarrow"> 
            <OPTION value="<? echo $row['destination']; ?>" selected ><? echo $row['destination']; ?></option>
            <option>
            <?=$optionsdestination?> 
            </option>
            </SELECT> 
        </td>
        <td>
            <SELECT name="correctedcycletype<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>" id="correctedcycletype<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>"  class="selectnarrow"> 
            <OPTION value="<? echo $row['cycletype']; ?>" selected ><? echo $row['cycletype']; ?></option>
            <option>
            <?=$optionscycle?> 
            </option>
            </SELECT> 
        </td>
        <td>
            <SELECT NAME="rate<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>" id="rate<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>" class="select"> 
            <OPTION VALUE=0 >
            <?=$optionsrate?> 
            </option>
            </SELECT> 
        </td>
        <td><? if($row['adminstatus']="approvereject"){ if(isset($row['approvedby'])){echo "Rejected by<font color=red> ".$row['approvedby']."</font>:  ".$row['lmcomments'];}}  ?></td>    </tr>
<? } ?>
</table>

<input type="submit" name="testupdate" id="testupdate" value="Updated selected">
<input type="submit" name="park" id="park" value="Park Selected">

</form>
```

As mentioned this used to work fine. now it doesn't. to troubleshoot, I removed some lines from the table, and this now works and passes post values to the next page.

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="bsassigncosts.php" method="post">
<table id="hor-minimalist-a">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Date & Time</th>
        <th><font color=red>Trailer</font></th>
        <th><font color=red>Load Number</font></th>
        <th><font color=red>Weight</font> kg's</th>
        <th><font color=red>Source</font></th>
        <th><font color=red>Destination</font></th>
        <th><font color=red>Cycle Type</font></th>
        <th><font color=red>Rate to be applied</font></th>
        <th>LOC Status / Comments</th>
    </tr>
<? while($row = $loads->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>"></td>
        <td><? echo $row['sarrive']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <SELECT name="correctedtrailer<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>" id="correctedtrailer<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>"  class="selectnarrow"> 
            <OPTION value="<? echo $row['trailer']; ?>" selected ><? echo $row['trailer']; ?></option>
            <option>
            <?=$optionstrailer?> 
            </option>
            </SELECT> 
        </td>   
        <td><input type="text" name="correctedloadnumber<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>" id="correctedloadnumber<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>" value="<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>" class="inputsmall"> </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="correctedweight<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>" id="correctedweight<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>" value="<? echo $row['weight']; ?>" class="inputsmall"> </td>

        <td><? if($row['adminstatus']="approvereject"){ if(isset($row['approvedby'])){echo "Rejected by<font color=red> ".$row['approvedby']."</font>:  ".$row['lmcomments'];}}  ?></td>




    </tr>
<? } ?>
</table>
</form>
```

if I add even one more entry, in the below code to the table, the post now fails. I cannot understand it:

```
<td>
    <SELECT name="correctedsource<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>" id="correctedsource<? echo $row['loadnumber']; ?>"  class="selectnarrow"> 
    <OPTION value="<? echo $row['source']; ?>" selected ><? echo $row['source']; ?></option>
    <option>
    <?=$optionssource?> 
    </option>
    </SELECT> 
</td>
```

Any advice here would be appreciated. Apologies if this is a really simple or stupid problem.

Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Comment: Which is the line you removed to get it to work? I'll be easier if you tell us, rather than us having to figure it out from the two separate snippets.

Comment: Did you check if you have a PHP error somewhere? (Enable PHP error reporting for debugging with: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`)

Comment: Your code is written in a really poor way that would make it almost impossible to maintain long term.  Also, the 'font' attribute is no longer valid HTML

Comment: `if($row['adminstatus']="approvereject")` You assign to $row here. `if(isset($row['approvedby']))` Will probably also be true if `$row['approvedby'] = "";`

Comment: What is the value of `$row['source']` could it be that it has a `"` in it?

Comment: Give us a link to forms' result HTML please, the one that doesn't submit

Comment: @Smudger We need to see the result HTML, what you code generates. So we can see where are the errors in it that prevent the form to be submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question frustratingly lay not in the code itself but in the number of form fields being passed.

I reduced the number of mysql rows in the while loop and resubmitted the form and it processed successfully. on [research](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php) the `max_input_vars` field is set to 1000. I am presuming this is the source of the issue and have logged a call with my hosting company to change the php.ini parameter for me.

Thanks for the help,